# Using a single generic Command for handling multiple Buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, mvvm

I am building a simple Calculator application. I'm also learning how to apply the MVVM pattern in my app.

I would like each one of the "Digit" buttons of my calculator to bind to the same Command, where they would only differ in the digit (Text) of the button that raised the command.

For example, When button "1" is clicked, i would like to receive the notification about it, extract "1" from the Sender's property, and continue the rest of the work needed.

This allows me to define a single method instead of 10 different handlers.

This is not possible as far as what i've seen in all MVVM tutorials till now, since the Command binding does not provide all this information to me when binding to the actual method that will handle the click.

Is there any way to easily do what i require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, you can use the `CommandParameter` property to let different buttons supply values to the same command. For example:

```xml
...
    <Button Content="1" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>

    <!-- Or, bind directly to the button's content using RelativeSource, like so: -->
    <Button Content="2" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"                    
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"/>
...
```

And in your command's delegate method:

```cs
private void ButtonClickCommandHandler(object parameter)
{
    switch(int.Parse(parameter.ToString()))
    {
        case 1:
        ...
        case 2:
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i did. Two small issues -- can i refer to the button's Content only once? Meaning, in the CommandParameter to "reference" the Content instead of writing it again? and second issue - what would be the runtime type of the argument that is passed as a CommandParameter? how is it determined?

Comment: @liortal: `CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Comment: The CommandParameter appears to be passed as a `string`, and so the handler should arguably use `int.Parse` to retrieve the integer. I've updated my answer to address your questions.

Comment: I know this is an extremely old post but it came up when searching for trying to solve this exact issue.  Doesn't this technically break MVVM pattern?  The view is being relied upon to do more than just display data.  It is now creating data and passing to the VM.

Comment: @GarudaLead It's been the better part of a decade since I worked with MVVM, and a year since your comment, but it's Friday so let's kick back: In the second example, where the `CommandParameter` is bound to the button content, if the `Content` were bound to a property of the VM, I believe MVVM would be preserved — the View would just be proxying a value from one place to another. **Caveats:** I'm not sure this would _work_ (and can't readily test it), and it seems like a good argument for why MVVM for a Calculator might be overkill! What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

Just provide the digit as a [`Button.CommandParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx). (Which is passed as a method parameter of [`ICommand.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx) (and [`CanExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx)))